# Requested operation requires an OLE DB Session object -- VB6 to SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql-server, vb6

I'm attempting to get into a VB6 application that was written for a client about a decade back, but intermittently I keep getting this error. The application has a login required upon launch, and upon entering the login provided for me (I am 100% certain it is correct), the following error is given:

> Run-time error '3709'
>   Requested operation requires an OLE DB Session
>   object, which is not supported by the current provider.

What's truly bizarre is that last night I was able to log in with absolutely no problems. However, I had this problem before about a week back, but I was out of town for several days and when I cam back I could log in again. Before that initial instance, I was able to log in fine. I noticed a similar question already posted, but the solution that was given did not work for me. Here's the code pertaining to establishing the database connection. Note, the Serv1, Use1, PW1 etc are just fillers for server names/usernames/passwords.

```
Public Function GetConnected()

' This function decides which server to connect and makes the connection

'Determines which connection string to use
If frmSplash.Text1 = "1" Or frmSplash.Text1 = "apc" Then 'server location
'determines if the logon contains '1' or 'apc'
    'APC connection code
    strSQLServerName = "(Serv1)"
    strSQLDBUserName = "Use1"
    strSQLDBPassword = "PW1"
    strSQLPort = ""

ElseIf frmSplash.Text1 = "2" Then
    'Laptop connection string
    strSQLServerName = "(Serv1)"
    strSQLDBUserName = "Use2"
    strSQLDBPassword = "PW2"
    strSQLPort = ""
Else
    'Client connection code
    strSQLServerName = "Serv2
    strSQLDBUserName = "Use3"
    strSQLDBPassword = "PW3"
    strSQLPort = ""
End If 'server location


    'If (m_DBConnection Is Nothing) Then
    Set m_DBConnection = New ADODB.Connection
    'End If

    SessionLocation = frmSplash.LocationCombo.Text

'***************************************
'Connecs to database based on location
    If frmSplash.LocationCombo.Text = "Loc1" Then
    strSQLDBName = "ServLoc1"
    ElseIf frmSplash.LocationCombo.Text = "Loc2" Then
    strSQLDBName = "ServLoc2"
    Else
    strSQLDBName = "ServLoc3"
    End If
'**************************

'Builds connection string
    m_DBConnection.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;" & _
    "Data Source = '" & strSQLServerName & strSQLPort & "';" & _
    "uid=" & strSQLDBUserName & ";" & _
    "pwd=" & strSQLDBPassword & ";" & _
    "Database=" & strSQLDBName & ";"  

On Error GoTo errorhandler
    m_DBConnection.Open
    If (m_DBConnection Is Nothing) Then
        MsgBox "Connection Failed"
    End If
Exit Function

errorhandler:
    MsgBox ("Problem with the Server")
    'MsgBox "Connection State " & GetState(m_DBConnection.State)
End Function

Public Function ExecuteSQL(strSQL As String) As ADODB.Recordset
    'Dim cmd As ADODB.Command

    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command

    **cmd.ActiveConnection = m_DBConnection** <-----(Error occurs here)
    cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
    cmd.CommandText = strSQL

    Set ExecuteSQL = cmd.Execute

Exit Function
```

Variable definitions:

```
Public strSQLServerName  'Holds the name of the SQL Server
Public strSQLDBUserName  'Holds the user name (for SQL Server Authentication)
Public strSQLDBPassword  'Holds the password (for SQL Server Authentication)
Public strSQLDBName      'Holds name of a database on the server
Public strSQLPort        'Holds the Port Number
Public SessionUser As Integer    ' To Track the type of User (3 Levels)
Public SessionLocation As String ' To Track the DB throughout the Session
Public m_DBConnection As ADODB.Connection
Public cmd As ADODB.Command
```

This is my first time working in VB6 and I'm a bit at a loss. I can't figure out why it works sometimes and not others. If anyone has any insights, they'd be very much appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like the connection was not opened successfully, or it was closed on another line of code not mentioned here. This error can easily be debugged. `debug.print` the connection state before the line that produces the error.

Answer (score 0):

Change your error handling to get a better idea of what is going on. Since you are setting your conncection (Set m_DBConnection = New ADODB.Connection) to a new object, your check (m_DBConnection Is Nothing) doesn't do much since the ojbect is certain to already exist.